# Reorder file name in folder with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have many files that I would like to reorder the name of.

Currently the file names read as

```
XXX-YYYYY-ZZZ-A1B2C3
```

I would like to reorder A1B2C3 to ABC123.

```
XXX-YYYYY-ZZZ-ABC123
```

The XYZ portion of the string will be variable lengths for each file, the A1B2C3 will always be at the end of the string.

Being able to batch over all files in the current folder is a good starting point, and batching over all files in the current folder and all subdirectories would be even better.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is `A1B2C3` portion length = six characters _always_?

Comment: I've had excellent result using the Flexible Renamer tool by Naru (http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA014830/english/FlexRena/). It allows but does not require Regex and offers a realtime GUI preview of the resulting changes before committing. Could be benefical if your requirements change one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /A-D /B *.*') do (
   for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=-" %%a in ("%%~Nf") do (
      set "last=%%d"
      set "new=!last:~0,1!!last:~2,1!!last:~4,1!!last:~1,1!!last:~3,1!!last:~5,1!"
      ECHO ren "%%f" "%%a-%%b-%%c-!new!%%~Xf"
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat
ren "XXX-YYYYY-ZZZ-A1B2C3.ext" "XXX-YYYYY-ZZZ-ABC123.ext"
ren "XXX-YYYYY-ZZZ-X9Y8Z7.ext" "XXX-YYYYY-ZZZ-XYZ987.ext"
```

Some points about this code:

- Your description say nothing about file *extension* so I assumed that the files have one. If not, just remove the `%%~Xf` part in the ECHO ren command.
- The last command just *show* in the screen the REN commands. If the REN commands looks correct, remove the ECHO part in order to *execute* the REN. You may also duplicate this line in order to see the REN commands when they are executed.
- To also process all subdirectories, add /S switch in DIR command this way: `dir /A-D /B /S *.*`
- If you have also other files that don't needs renaming, you may select just these files changing the `*.*` wild-card in DIR command by `*-*-*-*.*`

Comment: This is more what I thought would be possible, thanks for that. 
The command shows 'ren "A1B2C3.xxx" "A1B2C3---~0,1 .... ~5.1.xxx"'
I'm sure it's a simple fix and I understand how it works but don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: The files _must have_ the XXX,YYY,ZZZ parts as in `XXX-YYYYY-ZZZ-A1B2C3.ext` accordingly to your specifications!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which operating system you're using. I'll presume you're using *nix (Linux, OSX, BSD, etc); on Windows you could always install Perl and/or Cygwin.

Using the following **rename** script, you can write [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to rename your files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                           

# rename - fix up file names                                                    
# examples:                                                                     
# rename 's/\.orig$//' *.orig                                                   
# rename 'tr/A-Z/a-z/ unless /^Make/' *                                         
# rename '$_ .= ".bad" *.f                                                      

$op = shift or die "Usage: rename expr [files]\n";                              
chomp(@ARGV = <STDIN>) unless @ARGV;                                            
for (@ARGV)                                                                     
{                                                                               
  $was = $_;                                                                    
  eval $op;                                                                     
  die $@ if $@;                                                                 
  rename($was, $_) unless $was eq $_;                                           
}
```

(*Note*: I didn't write this **rename** script - it's been kicking around the internet for years).

For example, to remove the **XXX-** from the start of all your files, you would do:

```
~/bin/rename 's/^XXX-//' *
```

The regex for renaming **A1B2C3** to **ABC123** is left as *an exercise for the reader*.

Comment: It is for Windows; see the description of the `batch-file` tag: "A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on DOS, OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems."

Comment: I must say I'm a complete beginner, I'm on windows. I do have the Bulk Renaming Tool installed, that has RegEx functionality.. is it possible to use this tool instead?
My really crude attempt after googling (that doesn't work) is something like s/(\d{16})-(\d{1})-(\d{1})-(\d{1})-(\d{1})-(\d{1})-(\d{1})/$1-$2-$4-$6-$3-$5-$7/;

Comment: @Aacini to do this OP will almost definitely need to use regexes; installing Perl would be one easy way of achieving this. I will pay attention to the tags in future :-)

Comment: That is not true; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745000/reorder-file-name-in-folder-with-batch-script/30753336#30753336). Your solution just force the OP to face additional requirements.